# How to put href containing % in command

Tags: macros, hyperref

The following

```
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\newcommand{\mylink}{\href{http://foo.edu/level%20one.html}{Answer}}
```

gives an error because of the % sign. Is there a work around?

Comment: The solution here is the same as the other question. But searching for "href" and "command" didn't call up the results for "url" and "footnote".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent sign can be escaped with a backslash:

```
\newcommand{\mylink}{\href{http://foo.edu/level\%20one.html}{Answer}}
```